# Load homemade game onto emulator?

Tags: retropie, games

I want to load a game I've built onto an emulator like retropie, so it loads alongside all the other games in the menu, etc.

Currently, it's in p5.js, but I'm also working on a version in unity. So I guess the question is can you load different file types other than the classic game roms and if so how? Do you have to export/convert the game to a rom somehow?